Conditional initialization for integration tests
I have an ASP.NET Core app and integration tests for this API. I use xunit library to write these tests. The tests have the following structure:
public class AccountControllerTests : IAsyncLifetime
{
    public async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
       // database initialization here. 
       // inserting default values to tables
    }


    // some tests here
    [Fact]
    public void Test1() 
    {

    }

    pulic async Task DisposeAsync()
    {
        // database cleanup 
    }
}

It works fine but many of these tests do not require database initialization and cleanup. For example if I send http request with incorrect data to test some validation rules in my endpoint I expect a bad request result. This test fails before any database query would be performed. So I would like the initialization logic to be optional because it slows down the tests' execution. And I want to apply init/cleanup logic only for the tests which need it. Unfortunatelly InitializeAsync and DisposeAsync (Setup and TearDown) methods are performed for every single test. I could divide my test classes into two parts (tests which need db initialization and tests which don't) but maybe there is more elegant solution?

IMHO separating test classes are the cleanest solution.  It would be much more readable and easier to understand for the test reader, and on top of that it would be easier to execute those tests separately (if needed at all)

It is by design not possible with xUnit that initialization-methods (ctor / InitializeAsync) would make rules regarding test-methods. Reason is strict: initialization-methods precede test-method (it is basically an object-oriented principle).
You could, however, create a single connection for all tests (if it serves your testing agenda) by using class-fixture.
If making a connection is part of test-flow (i.e. depends on specific use-case) then I would recommend against creating connection prior to all tests. If under use-case #1 database NOT required then skip connection under test #1. If under use-case #2 database IS required then make a connection under test #2.
